# Probability of rolling $4$ or less on three dice in a dice pool of four

Tags: probability, dice

Here is my question:

> Imagine that on a $6$-sided die, each die that lands on $4$ or less counts as a hit. Each time you roll all four dice in your dice pool at once, you want to get at least three hits. What is the probability of that happening?

I have some ideas, but I'm not totally sure if they make sense, they're just intuition. It's not a straight probability like $(\frac{2}{3})^4$ because only three need to hit, but it's not raised to the $3^{rd}$ either because you have that extra die. The best I could come up with is $\frac{2+2+2+3}{3\cdot{4}}=\frac{9}{12}=0.75$, but I can't think of how to back that up with a proof. Any ideas?

Comment: $P(\text{Hits} \geq 3) = P(\text{Hits} = 3) + P(\text{Hits} = 4) = \binom{4}{3} \big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^3 \big(\frac{1}{3}\big) + \binom{4}{4} \big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^4$

Comment: $\left(\frac23\right)^4$ is the probability that all $4$ dice show $4$ or less.  Now you have to add the probability that exactly $3$ show $4$ or less.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer would be fine if you're looking at 4 successes, because with four dice, there's only 1 option that gets you there - SSSS. That's $(\frac{2}{3})^4$, straightforward enough. However, there's multiple ways of getting three successes from 4 dice - you could have SSSF or SSFS or SFSS or FSSS, so we have to account for all of these options. All of these option have the same probability, which is $(\frac{2}{3})^3(\frac{1}{3})^1$, but we need to add them all together, ultimately. Fortunately, we know the answer to this - it's a binomial coefficient, or a combination.

We add all this together, and can derive the equation below for finding the probability of $x$ successes in such a setup:

$$P(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$

where $n$ is the number of trials, and $p$ is the probability of success. This is also known as the *binomial distribution* equation, and when you're looking at success-based dice scenarios, this is usually your go-to equation.

Now, we know $n=4$, and we know $p=\frac{2}{3}$. We have two values of $x$ we care about - 3 and 4. So, to get the probability we just need to put both of those $x$ values through the equation, and add them together:

\begin{align}P(X\geq3) &= \binom{4}{3}\left (\frac{2}{3} \right)^3 \left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right )^{4-3} + \binom{4}{4}\left (\frac{2}{3}\right )^4\left (1-\frac{2}{3}\right )^{4-4}\\
&=(4)\left (\frac{8}{27}\right )\left (\frac{1}{3}\right ) + (1)\left (\frac{16}{81}\right )(1)\\
&= \frac{32}{81} + \frac{16}{81}\\
&= \frac{48}{81} = \frac{16}{27}
\end{align}